# How to preserve nested command substitutions inside a watch command

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I'm utilizing a watch command that has multiple commands strung together and they all work except one piece of it. Even when ran by itself it does not have the desired output.

Here is the watch command being ran.
`watch -n 5 echo "$(echo "$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')/$(nproc)*100" | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization"`

The output shows the cpu utilization at the time of execution but it does not update.
`Every 5.0s: echo 4.750% overall CPU utilization`

I'm almost certain it's a quoting issue somehow but I've been reading around and trying different things and can just not get it to work.
Here are some of the different versions of the command I've tried:

Using single quotes on the inside command sub

`watch -n 5 echo "$(echo '$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')/$(nproc)*100' | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization"`
`Every 5.0s: echo % overall CPU utilization % overall CPU utilization`

Escaping the single quotes on the inside command sub

`watch -n 5 echo "$(echo \'$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')/$(nproc)*100\' | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization"`
`Every 5.0s: echo % overall CPU utilization % overall CPU utilization`

Using single quotes on both sets of command sub, and escaping the inside set

`watch -n 5 echo '$(echo \'$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')/$(nproc)*100\' | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization'`
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token` )'`

Using single quotes on both sets of command sub (closest to desired output so far)

`watch -n 5 echo '$(echo '$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')/$(nproc)*100' | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization'`
`Every 5.0s: echo $(echo 0.24/8*100 | bc -l | cut -c-5)% overall CPU utilization 3.000% overall CPU utilization`

If I can determine how to get it to re-run `$(uptime | awk '{print$11}' | sed 's/,//g')` this each time then it should work.

Comment: How are those nested `echo`s not simply [useless?](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `watch` part should do, but you can vastly simplify this by refactoring all the processing into a single Awk script.

Something like this?

```sh
watch -n 5 'uptime | awk -v n="$(nproc)" "{cpu=\$11; gsub(/,/, \"\", cpu); printf \"%0.3f%% overall CPU utilization\\n\", cpu/n*100 }"'
```

The quoting is slightly pesky; you might want to save the single-quoted code as a script, which allows you to switch to single quotes around the Awk code and get rid of the backslashes.

Comment: I tried that but it throws this error:  
`sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'`
`sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Sorry, sloppy mobile typing ... Try now?

Comment: That does work when I run it by itself (thank you for that), but something falls apart when I add it to the other command in the watch.
`watch -n 5 "date && 'uptime | awk -v n="$(nproc)" "{cpu=\$11; gsub(/,/, \"\", cpu); printf \"%0.3f%% overall CPU utilization\\n\", cpu/n*100 }"' && echo \"Top 5 processes...\" && ps -Ao pid,ni,pmem,start_time,etime,pcpu,comm --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6"`  
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/,/,'`

Comment: You can't nest quotes like that; move `date &&` and the other commands inside the single quotes; or, conversely, remove the single quotes and refactor the command accordingly. Perhaps also read up on the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: Finally got it to work. Thank you for the help. I need to run this on dozens of servers that change from time to time so I didn't want to go the script or function route.

Answer (score 4):

To skip having to quote the command, you can use

```
myfunc() {
  insertYourCodeHere
}
export -f myfunc
watch -n5 bash -c myfunc
```